# force update many times :Gps Location during 3-6 seconds

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

my app need use new current GPS parameter(update after each from 3 to 8 second): latitude and longitude. and i am using both: GPS-provider and Network-provider.
i know use to update the GPS parameters

```
if(gps_enabled)
     lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);

if(network_enabled)
     lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
```

*The Problem: in fact, the gps update after each environ 40-50 second*

**How can i get the GPS update after 3-8 seconds ??**

thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
                try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
```

//lm is locationManager

In fact. i don't use the condition: network_enabled or Network-provider to get Location. ---> It work and the new code:

```
 lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListenerGps);
```

The reason, i don't use the Network_Provider. Because, when 2 GPS and Network Provider, system will use the NEtwork_provider. But in the logcat, i see that Smartphone does not update"Listenter" loop 3-6s with Network_provider.
En revanche, with GPS_PROVIDER, smartphone update alway 3-6s.

-- First time when open GPS; i need 30-50second to have the first Listener. But it is OK

Answer (score 2):

I've written a little app that will return position, average speed and current speed. When I run it on my phone (HTC Legend) it updates 1-2 times a second. You're more than welcome to use it if you like. you just need to create a main.xml file with 6 textviews and then add this line to your AndroidManifest.xmll file:

```
package Hartford.gps;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GPSMain extends Activity implements LocationListener {

LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

//text views to display latitude and longitude
TextView latituteField;
TextView longitudeField;
TextView currentSpeedField;
TextView kmphSpeedField;
TextView avgSpeedField;
TextView avgKmphField;

//objects to store positional information
protected double lat;
protected double lon;

//objects to store values for current and average speed
protected double currentSpeed;
protected double kmphSpeed;
protected double avgSpeed;
protected double avgKmph;
protected double totalSpeed;
protected double totalKmph;

//counter that is incremented every time a new position is received, used to calculate average speed
int counter = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    run();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    super.onPause();
}

private void run(){

    final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    //Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {

            counter++;

            //current speed fo the gps device
            currentSpeed = round(newLocation.getSpeed(),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            kmphSpeed = round((currentSpeed*3.6),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            //all speeds added together
            totalSpeed = totalSpeed + currentSpeed;
            totalKmph = totalKmph + kmphSpeed;

            //calculates average speed
            avgSpeed = round(totalSpeed/counter,3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            avgKmph = round(totalKmph/counter,3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            //gets position
            lat = round(((double) (newLocation.getLatitude())),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            lon = round(((double) (newLocation.getLongitude())),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
            longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);             
            currentSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);
            kmphSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kmph);
            avgSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.avgspeed);
            avgKmphField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.avgkmph);

            latituteField.setText("Current Latitude:        "+String.valueOf(lat));
            longitudeField.setText("Current Longitude:      "+String.valueOf(lon));
            currentSpeedField.setText("Current Speed (m/s):     "+String.valueOf(currentSpeed));
            kmphSpeedField.setText("Cuttent Speed (kmph):       "+String.valueOf(kmphSpeed));
            avgSpeedField.setText("Average Speed (m/s):     "+String.valueOf(avgSpeed));
            avgKmphField.setText("Average Speed (kmph):     "+String.valueOf(avgKmph));

        }

        //not entirely sure what these do yet
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, locationListener);
}

//Method to round the doubles to a max of 3 decimal places
public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode)
{
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
    BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
    return rounded.doubleValue();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The minTime parameter of `requestLocationUpdates` should be 3000 to 8000

```
public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)
```

`minTime    the minimum` time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.

`minDistance` the minimum distance interval for notifications, in meters

Comment: Hi Reno
in fact, i did setting the minTime : 3000 or 8000; but it did not work; And theory,  requestLocationUpdates(provider,0,0,listener) will notify more frequently. But it still 40-50 to update. Thanks

Comment: you are right; after i remove the condition: gps_enable and network_enable, it work

Comment: Yes it takes some time to get the first fix. It can be from 40 seconds to 10minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [requestLocationUpdates(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29)

```
public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
```

> Since: API Level 1
>
> Registers the current activity to be notified periodically by the named provider. Periodically, the supplied LocationListener will be called with the current Location or with status updates.
>
> It may take a while to receive the most recent location. If an immediate location is required, applications may use the getLastKnownLocation(String) method.
>
> In case the provider is disabled by the user, updates will stop, and the onProviderDisabled(String) method will be called. As soon as the provider is enabled again, the onProviderEnabled(String) method will be called and location updates will start again.
>
> The frequency of notification may be controlled using the minTime and minDistance parameters. If minTime is greater than 0, the LocationManager could potentially rest for minTime milliseconds between location updates to conserve power. If minDistance is greater than 0, a location will only be broadcasted if the device moves by minDistance meters. To obtain notifications as frequently as possible, set both parameters to 0.
>
> Background services should be careful about setting a sufficiently high minTime so that the device doesn't consume too much power by keeping the GPS or wireless radios on all the time. In particular, values under 60000ms are not recommended.
>
> The calling thread must be a Looper thread such as the main thread of the calling Activity.
>
> Parameters
>
> provider  the name of the provider with which to register
>
> minTime   the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.
>
> minDistance   the minimum distance interval for notifications, in meters
>
> listener  a {#link LocationListener} whose onLocationChanged(Location) method will be called for each location update

Comment: Thanks Aleadam,
But i cann't still find the solution.
Google Map or Navigation, they can update the location after interval 2-4seconds or some metres. Therefor,  May be we have a solution ?

Comment: @maydenec are you moving? You won't receive any location update unless the location changed.

Comment: Sorry, i have a mistake
I have just done with a Simple GPSlocation. It work,